# Scala: Create File with a Folder Using Relative Path (Not Absolute Path)

Tags: scala, file

In my Scala code I want to create a folder "c:/temp" and then create a file "file.txt" within that folder. I don't want to have to use "c:/temp/file.txt". So, I want to use the relative path of the file to create it within that folder.

Imagine how a human creates a folder and then a file? He creates a folder; goes in the folder, and then creates the file inside that folder. That's what I want to do.

=====

Added the following to make this more clear:
Let's say I created the folder and I have a File object called myFolder that represents that folder. What I want is to be able to do something like myFolder.createFile("file.txt").

Comment: *I want to create a folder "/temp"* : Do you want to create this directory in the root folder of the system `/` ?

Comment: Yes, the path to the folder is absolute path.

Comment: `Files.createDirectory(Paths.get("/temp"))` provided that you have root priviledges.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain clearly.  I don't care about the root part; I don't worry about the permission.  I changed the question to make it more clear.

Comment: It is not more clear ;) You can use the Java instruction in my previous comment to create a directory from a string. After folder creation. You can use the path `temp` to write files inside the newly created directory.

Comment: OK; let's say I created the folder and I have a File object called myFolder that represents that folder.  What I want is to be able to do something like myFolder.createFile("file.txt").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183060/discussion-between-jrook-and-user1888243).

Answer (score 1):

```
val subFile = new File(myFolder, "file.txt")
```

From the description of the `File(File parent, String child)` constructor found at the [docs page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html):

> Creates a new File instance from a parent abstract pathname and a child pathname string.

Comment: The OP is asking if they can do: `myFolder.createFile("file.txt")` with `myFolder` being some object representing the destination folder.

Comment: This is a correct answer to this question, please ignore the comment from @jrook.